# Rails app, REMOTE_USER attribute in IIS 8.5 with windows authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, windows-authentication, iis-8

I have setup a IIS 8.5 server that runs a rails app using `HttpPlatformHandler` and Windows authentication. We have also tried using ARR as reverse proxy with same results.

This all works completely fine, users are authenticated using kerberos, and anonymous authentication is disabled, no problem there.
We can deny specific users and see that it has effect.

The problem is that there is no `REMOTE_USER` or `AUTH_USER` attribute anywhere in the http response headers. However the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header is set and is eg "Negotiate YIIHJAYGKw....".

We haven't found a reasonable way to decode the `HTTP_AUTORIZATION` header either.

Any form of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hey Victor, have you had any luck with this? We are in a very similar situation.

Comment: Yes, i solved it, i will write a full report on how i did it tomorrow.

Comment: Alright i added the answer now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix this, you need to install helicontech's ISAPI_Rewrite 3 on the server running IIS. download url is here: [ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/download.html).

After that navigate to the install folder, the default is `C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3`

In there you will find a file called httpd.conf, open it up and add:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
RewriteHeader X-Remote-User: .* %{REMOTE_USER}
```

Now you will be able to get the remote username in your ruby code with:

```
request.env['HTTP_X_REMOTE_USER']
```

Comment: Thanks Victor this works great. Where you able to remove the username and password prompts from the browser?

Comment: Yes by using windows authentication and turning every other option off, on the IIS server

Comment: @VictorGram any idea how to get a windows username from an ubuntu server that runs a flask application?